# What is this plant that resembles a tomato with dark veins and stem base?

Tags: identification, seedlings

I was given a portion of a flat that has starts that resemble tomato plants, except that they have dark veins on their leaves and the base of their stems is the same dark color.

What could they be?

Comment: Welcome to the site, Tanya! To properly answer your question, we will need pictures of the plant, and some information on where you are located. etc. Thanks.

Comment: Does the person you recieved the plant from know? (I mean, did you ask them?)